# Linq To SQL: Sort Query by Arbitrary Property(Column) Name

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a larger/more complex problem, but for simplicity sake, let us consider the following:

Let us say that I have table in the **SQL DataBase** called **Product**, having two columns, **ID** *(int, primary key)* and **Name** *(varchar/string)*. I also have a simple **LINQ DataContext**.

I have a query constructed and handed to “my” function. Let us say it is something like: *(though it may be a bit more complex)*

```
IQueryable<Product> query = from p in db.Products select p;
```

Once my method gets this query, passed in as a parameter, it has to change the sort order e.g.

```
IQueryable<Product> sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

I would like to make this more generic i.e. to specify the field to sort on. Normally, I can do a `switch` statement that takes a string. However I would like to know if there is a way to pass the parameter directly. I intend to extend this to other Database tables, so these `switch` statements would get tedious.

I was trying something like:

```
IQueryable<Product> sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(x => (typeof(Product)).GetProperty(“Name”));
```

But this does not work. I also want to ensure that the LINQ to SQL is maintained i.e. the sort to be done on the SQL Server. Hence if I debug, I should get a SQL query from this LINQ query.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks to @Viper, I think I was really looking for **Dynamic LINQ** here. Using that I would simply have `IQueryable<Product> sortedQuery = query.OrderBy("Name asc");` which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Without getting too excited and looking at the green tick solution, you have described my exact problem with perfection. I was trying similar solutions to you as well. Getting excited about scrolling down!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `Dynamic Linq` for this purpose.

See here [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Then you can make calls like this:

```
var query = DBContext.Users.Where( "Age > 3" ).OrderBy( "Name asc" );
```

Comment: Thank you Viper. This is exactly what I was looking for. To others you need to install the Nuget package `System.Linq.Dynamic` and reference it to get this to compile.

Answer (score 13):

Try this out instead:

```
query.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(“Name”).GetValue(x, null));
```

You can't just grab the property. You need to grab the value off of that property, hence the call to `GetValue`.

Comment: Thank you Iron Man, but this does not work for me. If I later do a `sortedQuery.Count()`, I get an `InvalidOperationException` **Cannot order by type 'System.Object'**

Comment: I would also like to mention that if I cast the result, i.e. `sortedQuery.OrderBy(x => (Product)x.GetType().GetProperty(“Name”).GetValue(x, null));` I get the same exception message saying it it **Cannot order by type 'MyDataContext.Product'**

Comment: Of course it can't. 1) The object that `GetValue` returns is not of type Product anyway. It's only castable to the same type that the property is. 2) The LINQ has no clue how to order by `Product` anyway. You have to order based on primitive types.

Comment: Why do you say that LINQ has no clue how to order by Product, when `OrderBy(x => x.Name);` where `x` is a `Proudct` worked as in my original post?

Comment: Because that's not sorting by the `Product` object itself in that case. It's sorting based off of *name* which is a string primitive. That's ordering that LINQ can understand.

Comment: `OrderBy(x => x.Name);` is ordering by `Name`, which is a string.  To know how to order products it gets more complicated.  I believe you need to implement `IComparable` on your `Product` class in order to sort by OrderBy, though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Also, without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, this seems less effective than just writing it out.  But to get that working you need to cast it as whatever the properties type is (again, casting as `Product` doesn't work), so in the case of `"Name"`, cast as a string.

Comment: How can i use same like in where condition,

Comment: This answer works for me.  I am using the DataTables jQuery plugin, and when the DataTable sends a load request to the server, all it tells me is the string name of the column to order by.   I put that column name in the LINQ expression where the answer has "Name".  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as easy as it seems. The LINQ to SQL engine parses the expression you pass to the `OrderBy` method in order to obtain the name of the property you are referencing, then uses this information to compose a plain SQL `order by` clause.

I guess that maybe it can be done by using reflection, anyway. Maybe you can get something useful from the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby).