# Call OrderBy() with a field name as a string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using .NET 4.51, EF 6

I make a number of calls to my repository layer where I need to do some basic ordering on a single field in either ascending or descending order such as:

[image]

The result of `GetAllList()` is a `List<T>`. Now unfortunately the `Id` field I have to sort by is not always called `Id` nor is the `Text` field. They can be other things such as `MyId`, `SomeTextField` and so on.

So I was wondering if there was a way I could do the `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` clauses by supplying a string for the field name something like:

```
_Repository.GetAllList().OrderBy(r => r."SomeTextField")
```

In this way I could move all this code to a common method.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: the only way you'd be able to do exactly what you want with with reflection.  You should be able to use a `Func<T, TKey>` and accomplish the same thing without using strings though, like `LINQ` does

Comment: You can if the object is a DataRow() from a DataTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all. Rob, your solution was pretty close to what I ended up with.

Based on your insights I did some more searching and came across Marc Gravel's answer here [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet?rq=1) (second post).

It added dynamic's as an additional bonus.

Comment: Or just use https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389224  There's a System.Linq.Dynamic  nuget library that has  .OrderBy(string ordering)

So you can use it like:  list.OrderBy("firstName asc")

Answer (score 33):

This will work:

```
public static class LinqExtensions 
{
    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Type objType, string name)
    {
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();
        var matchedProperty = properties.FirstOrDefault (p => p.Name == name);
        if (matchedProperty == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("name");

        return matchedProperty;
    }
    private static LambdaExpression GetOrderExpression(Type objType, PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(objType);
        var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpr, pi.Name);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda(propAccess, paramExpr);
        return expr;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, string name)
    {
        var propInfo = GetPropertyInfo(typeof(T), name);
        var expr = GetOrderExpression(typeof(T), propInfo);

        var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propInfo.PropertyType);     
        return (IEnumerable<T>) genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, expr.Compile() });
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string name)
    {
        var propInfo = GetPropertyInfo(typeof(T), name);
        var expr = GetOrderExpression(typeof(T), propInfo);

        var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propInfo.PropertyType);     
        return (IQueryable<T>) genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, expr });
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
var r = new List<temp> { 
    new temp { a = 5 }, 
    new temp { a = 1 }, 
    new temp { a = 15 }
}.OrderBy("a");
```

Gives the correct result (1, 5, 15) - and will provide lazy execution for your use with EF

You will need to implement the overloads if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with EF core 3.1 too.

Comment: This is the simplest and most intuitive code, I have seen about this subject, easy to expand.

Answer (score 8):

Does it have to be a string? Why not just make a method that takes a `Func` key selector as a parameter.

```
public List<T> GetAllListOrdered<T,TProp>(SimpleOrderingDirectionEnum direction, Func<T,TProp> keySelector)
{
    return direction == SimpleOrderingDirectionEnum.Ascending ? _Repository.GetAllList().OrderBy(keySelector).ToList() : _Repository.GetAllList().OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
}
```

Then call it like

```
Func<ObjectToSortType, ObjectPropertyToSortBy> keySelector = r => r.Id;
GetAllListOrdered(SimpleOrderingDirectionEnum.Ascending, keySelector);
```

Comment: This will not translate to sql order by, if we use linq to entities, because linq to entities requires the expression tree for it. Use `Expression<Func<T,TProp>>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the Rob's answer is not enough for you. Try Linq Dynamic. http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic; //Import the Dynamic LINQ library

//The standard way, which requires compile-time knowledge
//of the data model
var result = myQuery
    .Where(x => x.Field1 == "SomeValue")
    .Select(x => new { x.Field1, x.Field2 });

//The Dynamic LINQ way, which lets you do the same thing
//without knowing the data model before hand
var result = myQuery
    .Where("Field1=\"SomeValue\"")
    .Select("new (Field1, Field2)");
```

Comment: I had considered this, but wanted to do something without pulling in yet another library. I did however end up utilising this in my preferred solution,