# Can it be done more cleaner and shorter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code which is in my opinion bad, because it has the similar statement repeated in each case statement:

```
if (command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc"))
{
   accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(o => o.NumberForSort).ToList();
}
else
{
   accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(o => o.NumberForSort).ToList();
}
```

**The only thing which is different is the property on which the query is ordered**.

```
switch (command.SortProperty.ToLower())
{
   case "number":
      if (command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc"))
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(o => o.NumberForSort).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(o => o.NumberForSort).ToList();
      }
      break;
   case "type":
      if (command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc"))
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(o => o.Type).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(o => o.Type).ToList();
      }
      break;
   case "employeename":
      if (command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc"))
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(o => o.EmployeeName).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
         accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(o => o.EmployeeName).ToList();
      }
      break;
   case "requestingemployeename":
         (...)

}
```

`accessForms.Forms` is a `List<>`. I would like to make this code more cleaner and shorter, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: This is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as you have working code. But I think you can at least create lamba expressions in the switch, and handle the sort order outside the switch.

Comment: You should not use TLower but ToUppad - .NET is optimized for upper comparison, not lower. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings

Comment: @TomTom You shouldn't use either.  You should use a case insensitive comparer if you want to compare strings in a case insensitive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, basically building a func extracting the sort field from a form and using it in the Linq operations.

Note that you could use a more strongly typed func, if the sort fields were all strings for instance.

```
Func<Form, object> sortFieldGetter = null;

switch (command.SortProperty.ToLower())
{
   case "number":
       sortFieldGetter = form => (object)form.NumberForSort;
       break;

   case "type":
       sortFieldGetter = form => (object)form.Type;
       break;

   case "employeename":
       sortFieldGetter = form => (object)form.EmployeeName;
       break;

   ...
}

if (command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc"))
{
    accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(sortFieldGetter).ToList();
}
else
{
    accessForms.Forms = accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(sortFieldGetter).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @rob code written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061770/call-orderby-with-a-field-name-as-a-string), in your case the final code can look like this:

```
 accessForms.Forms = command.OrderProperty.ToLower().Equals("asc")) ?
     accessForms.Forms.OrderBy(command.SortProperty.ToLower()).ToList() :
     accessForms.Forms.OrderByDescending(command.SortProperty.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Note that you need to implement your own OrderByDescending that isn't in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this question is perhaps better suited for Code Review.

In any case, you can do something along these lines:

Step 1: Create extension method(s)

```
public static IQueryable<T> SortByField<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> selector, bool ascending = true)
{
    return ascending ? source.OrderBy(selector) : source.OrderByDescending(selector);
}

public static IQueryable<T> SortByField<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> selector, string order = "asc")
{
    return SortByField(source, selector, order.Equals("asc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); //condition here can be improved, just as a sample of how to do it
}
```

Step 2: Enjoy:

```
 var samples = new List<Sample>().AsQueryable(); //you can of course use LINQ to SQL or EF, but I am lazy
 samples.SortByField(t => t.NumberForSort, false); //or "asc"
```

I think improving your "command"/query object would help clean up the code.

Rant: "Case" is for me a last resort, it almost always means that there are at least two places where I must change code, which might not always be located in the same assembly, and almost all uses of "case" can be replaced with Dictionary or the Strategy pattern.