# Can I take object property in Linq from string input?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can I take object property in Linq from string input?

For an example I have collection of clothes:

```
clothes.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

This will order them by Name, ok.
But user should can order them by also `Price`, `Type`, `Creation Date` and so on.

So is it possible to do something like:

```
clothes.OrderBy(x => x + "." + inputFilter);
```

Well this is obviously not working like this, but `OrderBy` doesn't have much methods either.

My idea is to skip some Switch Case construction, if there is some smarter way. 
Is it such way is my question?

(I`m using asp.net MVC with Razor engine.)

Comment: another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: Custom sorts are usually done in a class that inherits IComparable.

Comment: Personally It go with with a switch or if statements unless you plan to have a lot of changes made to the properties/columns of that class/table.

Comment: Use dynamic Linq - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388230/linq-to-sql-sort-query-by-arbitrary-propertycolumn-name